# Cordova project and windows platform

Tags: c, cordova

I have a cordova project and I added windows platform but when I run the project I have this error:

```
MSBuild v4.0 is not supported, aborting.
Error: AppPackages doesn't exists
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to set OS environment variable 
VSINSTALLDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\
which points to your Visual Studio folder with MSBuild directory.

Comment: Ok thank you, I tried, now I have this:

PS D:\project\cordova\test-menu-navigator> cordova run windows
Building project: D:\project\cordova\test-app\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj
        Configuration : debug
        Platform      : anycpu
Error: Windows SDK not found. Ensure that you have installed Windows 8.1 SDK along with Visual Studio or install Windows
8.1 SDK separately from https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads

Comment: Use --arch buid parameter to specify target platform like this:
cordova run windows --arch=x86 --verbose

Comment: Thank you, I solved installing Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017 in visualstudio.com/downloads/ section "Other tools and frameworks", with environment variable VSINSTALLDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\ and with <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" /> <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="10.0" /> in config.xml file.

Answer (score 3):

You have of install Microsoft Build Tools:

https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/

- Navigate to **Other Tools and Frameworks**
- Download *Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017*
- After, set OS environment variable VSINSTALLDIR = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\ which points to your Visual Studio folder with MSBuild directory